# Choice of data model: Nested map or vector for Reagent atom to be updated-in and mapped over?

Tags: data-structures, clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I'm working on a Reagent App to manage seasons for a hotel-booking-site. The data is shown in a tabular view and is currently stored in an atom holding a nested map with season-ids as keys, like so:

```
(def seasons (r/atom
{1
 {:begin "2020-04-02"
  :end "2020-04-19"
  :selected false
  …much more data like price per room etc}
2
{:begin "2020-04-20"
  :end "2020-06-18"
  :selected true
  }
…}))
```

The main advantage of this structure is easy deleting/modifying of seasons from within my components via `#(dissoc @seasons season-id)` or `(update-in seasons [season-id :begin] "2020-04-21")`, which would be more cumbersome with the flatter alternative of integrating the id into the map representing a season, like so:

```
(def seasons
(r/atom
[{:id 1
  :begin "2020-04-02"
  :end "2020-04-19"
  :selected false
  …much more data like price per room etc}
 {:id 2
  :begin "2020-04-20"
  :end "2020-06-18"
  :selected true
  }…]))
```

This version would lend itself much better to being mapped over, which is not very pleasant with my current data model, where I have to always recombine the id with the actual map into a binary vector and then stick the resulting seq back `into` a map.

I'm more and more inclined to switch to this second model as the removal/update would be feasible by passing the entire season into a function… there would be no need for ids at all then, e.g.:

```
(vec (remove #(= % season) @seasons))
```

or, respectively:

```
(vec (map #(if (= % season) 
       (update-in % [:begin "2020-04-21"]) %) @seasons))
```

Since this is my first real-world Reagent app I'm a bit unsure as to **which data model is actually preferable**? Are there any **performance considerations** between both approaches? Which one would seem more sane to a seasoned Reagent developer? Is there **a third way that I'm unaware of?**

Many thanks for any input to this somewhat open question!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Honourable mention for modifying nested datastructures and keep their structure: https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter

Comment: Thanks, I've meant to look into specter for some time… for my current project it's probably overkill though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe your purposes (seasons), performance is not a consideration.  Three "seasons" per day is only ~1000 per year - a small number to a computer.

So, which method is easier for your code?  You have discussed two use-cases which come down favoring method A in one case and method B in another.  It is up to you to decide.

In method A, you have "pre-indexed" the data, so you can go directly to a thing and modify it. In method B, you have to do a mini-search to find a thing, before processing it.  For a larger problem, method B eventually morphs into a DB like Postgres, Datomic, or Neo4J, etc.

For small problems that stay in memory, you could use a library:

- [Spectre](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter)
- [DataScript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript)
- [Tupelo.Forest](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc) - my personal favorite! ;)

These are probably overkill at this stage, but you may want to keep them in mind for the future.

Comment: Many thanks for your judgement… I understand that the choice isn't as obvious as I thought it might be in the eyes of a more advanced Clojurian and that the tradeoffs I'm seeing are in fact real and and not easily circumvented… I guess I'll try to refactor into version B… even if only for learning purposes. 

Tupelo.Forest looks great… Might solve a couple of hiccup-walking-attempts I've been making.